# How to use activated and deactivated in vue composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

How to use `activated` and `deactivated` keep alive events in a vue composition api?

I can't find any references [in the docs](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: i think you can still use `keep-alive` `activated/deactivated` in vue 2/3 - and think it might be out of scope of the composition api

Comment: there's onActivated – called when a kept-alive component is activated
onDeactivated – called when a kept-alive component is deactivated
 lifecycle hooks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for the vue composition api - you can still access the `activated/deactivated` lifecycle methods in vue, including within `vue-next`.

[vue.js 3/(beta)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/search?q=onActivated&unscoped_q=onActivated)

---

I believe the library `vue-composition-api` supports the activated/deactivated methods but isn't added to the docs.

[vue-composition-api](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/search?q=deactivated&unscoped_q=deactivated)

```
import {onActivated, onDeactivated} from "vue"

export default {
  setup() {
    onActivated(() => {
      // ... 
    })
    onDeactivated(() => {
      // ... 
    })
  }
}
```